# How the node CSRF protection works with angular resource?

Tags: node.js, angularjs

My node Server has the following configuration:

```
app.use(express.csrf());
app.use(function (req, res, next) { 
   res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', req.csrfToken());  
   next();  
});
```

The Token is grabbed by angular and send with the header. right?
But the token is only checked with out and post routes, not with get routes...is this right?

Is it possible to add the csrf protection for get routes too? Do I need a middleware?

Thanks!

Comment: XSRF-TOKEN(Cross Site Request Forgery token) is actually only used for forms submission and has no use on GET requests, could you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: thats ok for me...form methods are put, post? whats with delete?

Comment: Yes Deletes should also be validated how ever you don't need the second middleware, unless you are not using the out of the box approach from express

Answer (score 0):

GET requests are safe and idempotent: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Usually csrf is not necessary for GET, HEAD, OPTIONS requests.

If needed you can enable it for GET.

All popular libs allow you to enable to the types you need.

For example:  You can override defaults by setting "ignoreMethods" explicitly in https://github.com/expressjs/csurf